# TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined in react with context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slice, react-context

making my project with context api, I met an error ever can't understand why.

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined"

```
// context.js

import React, { useReducer, createContext, useContext } from "react";
import userData from "./data/bond.json";

const initialState = { user: userData, clickedState: [] };
console.log(initialState);
console.log(initialState.user);

function bondReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CLICK":
      return state.user.filter(bond => bond.id !== action.id);
    case "DELETE":
      return state.clickedState.filter(item => item.id !== action.id);
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
  }
}

const bondStateContext = createContext();
const bondDispatchContext = createContext();

export function BondProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(bondReducer, initialState);
  return (
    <bondStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <bondDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </bondDispatchContext.Provider>
    </bondStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useBondState() { // I made this to import the function in any component in handy.
  const context = useContext(bondStateContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot find BondProvider`);
  }
  return context;
}

export function useBondDispatch() {
  const context = useContext(bondDispatchContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(`Cannot find BondProvider`);
  }
  return context;
}
```

It's context.js to use context into other components.

```
// bondTable.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useBondState, useBondDispatch } from "../bondContext";
import Pagination from "./pagination";

function BondTable() {
  const Bonds = useBondState();
  console.log(Bonds); // object
  console.log(Bonds.user); // Array

  // pagination
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(8); // 

  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = Bonds.user.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost); // error invoked at this point.
  console.log(currentPosts);

  // Change pages
  const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

  // map bond's data
  const list = currentPosts.map(val => ({
    id: val.id,
    key: val.product_id,
    inBasket: false,
    product_code: val.product_code.slice(3) + "호",
    origin_principal: val.origin_principal.toLocaleString() + "원",
    rate: (val.rate * 100).toFixed(2) + "%",
    startAt: val.startAt.slice(0, 10),
    issueAt: val.issueAt.slice(0, 10),
    period: val.period + "일",
    leftTerm: dayCalculate(curDate, curDate)
  }));

  // Click row
  const dispatch = useBondDispatch(); // to use dispatch from context
  const clickRow = e => {
    dispatch({
      type: "CLICK",
      id: e.currentTarget.id
    });
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id); // knowing a row's id that I clicked.
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <TableBox>
          <tbody>
            {list.map((el, index) => (
              <Tr key={index} id={el.id} onClick={clickRow}>
                <Td>{el.id}</Td>
                <Td>{el.product_code}</Td>
                <Td></Td>
                <Td>{el.origin_principal}</Td>
                <Td>{el.rate}</Td>
                <Td>{el.startAt}</Td>
                <Td>{el.issueAt}</Td>
                <Td>{el.period}</Td>
                <Td>{el.leftTerm}</Td>
              </Tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </TableBox>
        <Pagination
          postsPerPage={postsPerPage}
          totalPosts={Bonds.user.length}
          paginate={paginate}
        />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default BondTable;
```

The page is rendered well at first, but when I clicked any row of table,
the error("cannot read property 'slice' of undefined") is showed up.
But if I set the 'initialState' in Context.js as 'const initialState = userData'
the error is not happened, onClick event is well functioned. 
And that's why I can't understand the error!! :(

please let me know the reason, and the point wrong. if you know the reason...

Comment: Can you also post your useBondState hook code? My guess is that Bonds property "user" is set later than it is being get(where error happens). Try to put "Bonds.user" inside setTimeout, just for testing, give delay a second, see output.

Comment: I post 'usebondState' function. And I couldn't understand your saying "My guess is that Bonds property "user" is set later than it is being get(where error happens).". I think I put it before where error happens, `const currentPosts = Bonds.user.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost); // error invoked at this point.
  console.log(currentPosts);`

Comment: What if you put console.log(Bonds.user) just before const currentPosts , will it drop undefined error?

Comment: it works well ;) console.log(bonds.user) is seen perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is this line:

```
return state.user.filter(bond => bond.id !== action.id);
```

you must do instead:

```
return {...state, user: state.user.filter(bond=>bond.id!==action.id)}
```

In any case, I recommend you take a look at [react-context-slices](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-context-slices). It's a library for using Context with 0 boilerplate, easy and fast. With this library you do it like this:

```
// slices.js
import getHookAndProviderFromSlices from "react-context-slices"
export const {useSlice, Provider} = getHookAndProviderFromSlices({
  count: {initialArg: 0},
  // rest of slices of Context you want to define
})
```

```
// app.js
import {useSlice} from "./slices"
const App = () => {
  const [count, useCount] = useSlice("count")
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setCount(c => c + 1)}>+</button>{count}
  </>
}
```

Hope it helps anyone planning to use Context API. Thanks.